# Unable to Parse Email in Python

Tags: python-3.x, email, parsing

I have set of .msg files stored in E:/ drive that I have to read and extract some information from it.
For that i am using the below code in Python 3.6.

```
from email.parser import Parser
with open("E:\Downloads\Test1.msg",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as fp:
    headers = Parser().parse(fp)

print('To: %s' % headers['To'])
print('From: %s' % headers['From'])
print('Subject: %s' % headers['subject'])
```

In the output I am getting as below.

```
To: None
From: None
Subject: None
```

Process finished with exit code 0

I am not getting the actual values in To, FROM and subject fields.

Any thoughts why it is not printing the actual values?

My sample .msg file looks like below.

```
From: Bournemouth.wmt@gmail.com
To: Francis.dell@gmail.com
Subject: orderid: ord1234, circtid: cr1234


Charges:
Annual Charge - 10
Excess Charges - 5
```

From this message I am trying to extract order id, circuit id from subject and charges from mail body.

Output1:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a sample of one of the email messages that doesn't yield to parsing?

Comment: Sample looks like,

Comment: I should clarify, it would be best if we could have access to that file you're attempting to process, the one called 'Test1.msg'. Could you put it on pastebin.com perhaps?

Comment: Hi Bill, I am not able to find an option for attachment in pastebin.com. I have attached a jpg file in description. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I've just noticed that this involves gmail. The only way of getting an email message from gmail produces a pdf.

Comment: OK, then pastebin.com should do what's needed. We don't require the attachment since you said you want only data from headers and the body. Save a typical message, then go to pastebin and copy-paste the entire message into the available area, save it and give us the pastebin url.

Comment: Hi Bill, here is link https://pastebin.com/1APkTqrp

Answer (score 1):

This is the body of the file that you posted on pastebin for us.

```
From: ratankumar.shivratri@TechM.com <ratankumar.shivratri@TechM.com>
Sent: Thursday, January 4, 2018 11:58 AM
To: Ratankumar Shivratri
Subject: Cct Id: ONE211, eCo order No: 1CTRP

Charges:

Annual rental - 2,125.00

Maintenance charge - 0.00



Regards

Ratan.
```

I've been able to obtain data from the headers using the following code.

```
>>> from email.parser import Parser
>>> p = Parser()
>>> msg = p.parse(open('ratan.msg'))
>>> msg['To']
'Ratankumar Shivratri'
>>> msg['From']
'ratankumar.shivratri@TechM.com <ratankumar.shivratri@TechM.com>'
>>> msg['Subject']
'Cct Id: ONE211, eCo order No: 1CTRP\n '
```

So that much works.

The next problem I foresee is that the format of the subject headers seems to be inconsistent across messages. For instance, in the message in your question, the subject header is 'orderid: ord1234, circtid: cr1234' but in this message it's 'Cct Id: ONE211, eCo order No: 1CTRP'. You want to be able to recover 'order id, circuit id' from messages but these items don't appear in every message.

If they did you could probably ferret them out with a regex.

Comment: Hi Bill, I am not able to get header messages that I tried with your code. Please refer screenshot (in description) of output I am getting.

Comment: Have you tried applying the code to the text you posted on pastebin (the version without line numbers)?

Comment: Yes. Please refer screenshot (output2). We are still getting header value 
 as None.

Comment: I regret, I can't duplicate the problem

Comment: Hi Bill, I am not able to read content from the msg file I have uploaded in drive. Can you please try. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwWWG3BgsMKwRr0WmP8GqzG3WX4GmEy6/view

Comment: I've had a look at it. I don't know how to do that either. You should post this as a question, possibly on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)